# Easy Way To Access change() from redux-form in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a need to update some form data, given a selection that is made.

I would like to do this in the onChange handler of a select field using the change() function from redux-form.

Is there a way to access the redux-form change function easily using standard react-admin?

I tried picking it up from props, but it is not there;

```
const { change } = this.props;
console.log(change); // undefined
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: What about writing a saga around the '@@redux-form/CHANGE' actions?

Comment: Will check that out

Comment: Did you solve this? If so, can you post an answer? Thx.

Comment: Redux-saga could solve it, but I did not circle back to this just yet.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for, but this is how I handled it in my react-admin project. I just imported `change` directly from `redux-form`, and passed it the `REDUX_FORM_NAME` constant from `react-admin`.

Imports

```
import { change } from 'redux-form'
import { REDUX_FORM_NAME } from 'react-admin'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
```

Edit Component

```
<Edit>
    <SimpleForm>
        <MyCustomComponent />
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
```

`MyCustomComponent` should receive a `record` prop automatically from `SimpleForm`. Also, I connected it to the redux store:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyCustomComponent)
```

I intentionally did not provide a second argment to `connect` so I could have access to `dispatch` in my component. Perhaps another way is possible, but that's what worked for me.

So now, inside `MyCustomComponent`, in a `handleCancel` handler I created for a Cancel button, I changed the fields I wanted to change. In my specific case, I wanted to reset the fields to contain the unmodified stored value for that field.

```
handleCancel = () => {
    const { record, dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(change(REDUX_FORM_NAME, 'name', record.name));
    dispatch(change(REDUX_FORM_NAME, 'description', record.description));
    dispatch(closeDetails()); // unrelated to this answer; closes a modal
}
```

In the code above, I reset the 'name' and 'description' fields to their original values. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Also, you can do `await dispatch(change(REDUX_FORM_NAME, ....` if you're going to be submitting the form with `handleSubmitWithRedirect` in the same handler.